# How to compile a Delphi source code file for execution from the command line with parameters?

Tags: windows, delphi-7, show-hide, delphi-2009

I use Delphi 7 IDE. I want to run .exe  from the command line with parameters (to be defined).

1. How can I know if my app is running with the CMD command?
2. How can I read the parameter with source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know if my app is running with the CMD command?

You can't, nor do you ever need to.  If your project is a console app, then the `.exe` is always run inside of a console window process.  If the project is not a console app, then there is no console, but you can create one if needed using [`AllocConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole).  Any process, whether it is a console app or not, can receive command-line parameter, though.

> How can I read the parameter with source code?

Use the [`ParamCount()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamCount) and [`ParamStr()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr) functions in the `System` unit, or the [`FindCmdLineSwitch()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindCmdLineSwitch) function in the `SysUtils` unit.

Or, use [`GetCommandLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea) in the `Windows` unit and parse the raw command-line data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var 

bHideForm = boolean ; 

begin 

bHideForm := False; 
bHideForm := ParamCount > 0;
if  bHideForm   then 
bMetadataExport := GetParamValue(C_MENU, sMetaDataMenu);

{--------------------- function GetParamValue ----------------------------- }
function GetParamValue(aParamName: string; out oParamValue: string): Boolean;
  var
    i: Integer;
    s: string;
  begin
    Result := False;
    for i := 1 to ParamCount do
    begin
      s := ParamStr(i);
      Result := pos(aParamName, UpperCase(s)) = 1;
      if Result then
      begin
        oParamValue := copy(s, length(aParamName)+2, MaxInt);
        Exit;
    
      end;

     end;

    end;

end;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).